# Adding Facebook Audience Network to a cross-platform libGDX game

Tags: android, ios, libgdx, cross-platform, facebook-audience-network

How can I add Facebook Audience Network to a cross-platform (Android and iOS via MOE) libGDX Game?

Comment: Yes obviously you can put the facebook audience network on button click or anywhere where you want to place.

Comment: @ShubhamSejpal I don't think you understood my question at all.